# Java 8 Collectors.toList source code

Tags: java-8, java-stream, collectors

In java sources, Collectors.toList is defined as:

```
public static <T>
Collector<T, ?, List<T>> toList() {
    return new CollectorImpl<>((Supplier<List<T>>) ArrayList::new, List::add,
                               (left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; },CH_ID);
}
```

Corresponding CollectorImpl constructor

```
CollectorImpl(Supplier<A> supplier,
                      BiConsumer<A, T> accumulator,
                      BinaryOperator<A> combiner,
                      Set<Characteristics> characteristics) {
            this(supplier, accumulator, combiner, castingIdentity(), characteristics);
        }
```

We see `List::add` as second parameter of `CollectorImpl`'s contructor,I am wondering how does it maps to accumulator which is of Type
`BiConsumer<A,T>` since `BiConsumer` consumes two parameter and `List::add` consumes one paramter only. What am I missing here?

Comment: The two parameters become actually `this` and the new element. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25512532/lambda-parameters

Comment: @AndrewTobilko No, the overload with 2 parameters would be the one taking the index at which to add the element, but this isn't the one refered to here. `List::add` can be seen as `(list, elem) -> list.add(elem);`.

Comment: @Tunaki, I didn't know, thanks