# Using method references on a instance to be determined at runtime in Java

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

I was testing out rules of using method references, but the code I wrote would not compile. The compiler keeps giving telling me that I cannot reference a non-static method from a static context. However, in the Java Documents it explicitly wrote that it is possible to use "::" to "reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type". Can anyone point out what's wrong with my code? Thank you!

```
package Test;
import java.util.function.BiPredicate;

class Evaluation {
    public boolean evaluate(int a, int b) {
        if (a-b ==5){
            return true ;
        }
        return false; 
    }

    public void methodTest() {
        BiPredicate<Integer, Integer> biPredicate = Evaluation::evaluate;
        System.out.println(biPredicate.test(6,1));
    }
}
```

Edit: After reading the answers, I was wondering if it is the case that referencing an instance method by the class name only works in some functional interfaces but not in other ones? For instance,

```
BiPredicate <String, Integer> biPredicate =  String::startsWith;
```

doesn't compile, while:

```
Predicate <String> predicate = String::isEmpty;
```

compiles. 
If this is the case, is there a page/tutorial/whatever that anyone can refer me to that explains which function interfaces are compatible and which are not?

Comment: See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25512532/lambda-parameters)

Comment: `String::startsWith` would take 3 arguments; 1. the `String` instance on which to invoke, 2. the `String` parameter `prefix` and 3. the `int` parameter `toffset`. But a `Bipredicate<String, Integer>` can only account for 2 of those. `String::isEmpty`, takes 1 parameter, the instance to invoke on, so a `Predicate<String>` _will_ work.

Comment: @JornVernee You are totally right. However, why does `Predicate <String> predicate = String::isEmpty; ` work? Like why don't I need to do pass a new instance of `String()`  (As your answer below to my original question may indicate)?

Comment: @EddieLin You will need to do that when you call it, the `test` method takes 1 parameter. It's doesn't have to be new though, any instance will work (in my answer, I just used `new Evaluation()` as an example)

Comment: @JornVernee When I call it it will be something like `System.out.println("predicate.test(""));`right? I do not need to create a new functional interface with a method that takes in something like `(Evaluation instance, String a)`. Why do I need to do so for my code with `BiPredicate`? Is `BiPredicate` a special case?

Comment: @Eddie Lin: As Jorn Vernee already explained with the `String::startsWith` example, an instance method taking two arguments results in a function taking three arguments. Your `evaluate` needs an `Evaluation` instance *and* two `int` arguments, hence, you need a function type having three parameters. Since **Bi**Function only has two parameters, it is inappropriate. And since there is no predefined `TriFunction` interface, you have to create your own interface.

Comment: Just consider that the method reference is the equivalent to `(instance, i, j) -> instance.evaluate(i, j)`. Three parameters.

Comment: @Holger That makes perfect sense now. If I change `Predicate <String> predicate = String::isEmpty;` to something like `Predicate <String> predicate = stringInstance::isEmpty;` it won't compile. Thanks for all your responses!

Answer (score 2):

If your method is an instance method, then you have to invoke it on some instance, for example:

```
public void methodTest(){
    BiPredicate<Integer, Integer> biPredicate = this::evaluate;
    System.out.println(biPredicate.test(6,1));
}
```

Since you are not using any instance variables or method, you can simply make it static and keep it like it is.

Comment: Was writing the same answer ;)

Comment: Since method doesn't use instance variables/methods, I'd say your answer is wrong, and that OP should simply make the method `static` instead. Alternatively, since the code is in a non-static method, why create a new instance? Use `this::evaluate`.

Answer (score 2):

When statically referencing an instance method, the returned functor takes an additional argument that represents the instance.

```
interface Func {
    boolean evaluate(Evaluation instance, int a, int b);
}
...
Func biPredicate = Evaluation::evaluate;
System.out.println(biPredicate.evaluate(new Evaluation(), 6, 1));
```

But you will need to pass an instance of `Evaluation` when calling it.

Since your `evaluate` method does not use any instance fields, you might as well make it `static`, then you don't need to pass an instance, and *can* use just a `BiPredicate<Integer, Integer>` like you tried to.

Comment: `Func biPredicate = Evaluation::evaluate` syntax error: *Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method evaluate(int, int) from the type Evaluation.* Introducing a new functional interface doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Andreas Try again, I had a typo there. It works fine for me :)

Comment: Would it be easier to just write `biPredicate = this::evaluate`, rather than creating a new functional interface? Or `biPredicate = new Evaluation()::evaluate` if you insist on using a new instance object *(though why?)*?

Comment: @Andreas That's a different solution, but I want to explain why OP's version doesn't work, and how to make it work. My suggestion was to make the method static.

Comment: Your code is a very long-winded way to implement `new Evaluation()::evaluate`.

Comment: @Andreas My code shows how statically referencing an instance method _actually_ works, it's long winded because there is no standard interface in `java.util.function` that you can use.

Comment: I was going to post this. This shows that you **can** reference an instance method with the class name, given that you can provide the correct functional interface.

Comment: @Andreas: this answer addresses the OP’s actual question. The argument of `new Evaluation()` is just an example, as the OP hasn’t provided an argument. But you can pass a different instance on each invocation…

Answer (score 0):

I'm still trying to figure out the rule that applies, but the problem goes away if you use

```
BiPredicate<Integer, Integer> biPredicate = this::evaluate;
```

I'm puzzling through https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13 but as near as I can figure, because the `Evaluation::evaluate` forces the compiler to create an arbitrary object of the type `Evaluation`, and you're calling it from within an object of that type, that the rule is different. You need to call it from the specific object inside of which the `methodTest` method appears.

While I don't have the explanation, the solution is to use `this::evaluate`. That unambiguously ties the method reference to the object calling it.

Side note: You don't need to evaluate a `boolean` as a conditional in order to derive a `boolean` from the `boolean`. You could just `return a - b == 5;`.

Answer (score 0):

I am probably way too late to answer this, but since the question is still unanswered I would like to attempt an answer.

I think there is a miss in what OP is trying to achieve.

I understand that OP is trying to understand, why something like this would work:

```
    String str = "abc";
    Predicate<String> methodRef = str::startsWith; 
    methodRef.test("s");
```

and then,

```
Predicate <String> predicate = String::isEmpty
```

Works and in similar fashion, why wouldn't

```
Predicate <String> predicate =  String::startsWith;
```

Compile which is taking String class name compile.

That is simply because, Predicate basically, takes any argument and returns a boolean. This is not a correct setup for this problem.

You can instead try,

```
BiFunction<String, String, Boolean> methodRef2 = String::startsWith;
methodRef2.apply("sdsdfsd", "sdfsdf");
```

This would work, as startswith needs a source string, string to check and return value. Basically there are 4 ways to invoke method references in Java 8

1. Static method calls.
2. Instance method calls.
3. Class method calls
4. Constructors